# Remove parents from list

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 lists, both containing objects which look like this: (this is a simplification)

```
class ddItem
{
    public string Code;
    public string Key;
    public string ParentKey;
}
```

One list contains items which may or may not have children in the other list.
I'm trying to figure out a nice way to remove items from the parent list if they have a corresponding item in the child list, i.e. where parent.Key = child.parentKey.

This is the LINQ I have, and it's currently causing me to lose brain cells:

```
parentList = 
    (List<ddItem>)parentList.Where(p => childList.Select(c => c.ParentKey == p.Key));
```

Currently I have a red squiggly line under `childList.Select(c => c.ParentKey == p.Key)` and the message `Cannot convert expression type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<bool>' to return type 'bool'` so I must be missing a cast somewhere - I think...

[EDIT]

For posterity, the correct code is:

```
parentList = 
    parentList.Where(p => childList.Any(c => c.ParentKey == p.Key)).ToList();
```

(I also had to move the cast)

[/EDIT]

Comment: The `.Where` expects a boolean results, but `.Select` returns a record.  Change the Linq so that it results in a boolean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need only to change from `select` to `any` in the `where`

```
parentList.Where(p => childtList.Any(c => c.ParentKey == p.Key))
```

Comment: (Just waiting the 10 minutes so I can mark as answer... :s)